# How does Whatsapp main activity launches so fast despite loading data, images for many chats?

Tags: java, android, performance, kotlin, whatsapp

It looks like google-search-needed type question, but the keyword "Whatsapp" is not letting any useful results come at the top.

Seems like they are using more than just Async tasks as when the activity is loaded even then the things are loaded.

I tried to make an app somewhat similar to Whatsapp but the loading time is too much for the main activity. What smart things are used in Whatsapp that make it load so fast despite having the need to load the names, images, some part of chats, and then create the views for each individual chats?

Are they using something like saving the data in some specific format, or what kind of things they are doing specially than the very standard ones?

Comment: I'd guess loading all data async, starting activity straight away and filling in data as it comes available. (you'll notice that for instance not all pictures are loaded if you scroll really fast for the first time after starting it)

Comment: I don't know why people down-voted this question. Even I am making a messaging app and I also wonder how apps like WhatsApp load messages so quickly. Do they store the list as an object as a whole so the next time the app launches just recreate the activity from that object? Please comment back if you get a satisfying answer, will ya?

Comment: @sweetpoision I think people downvoted it because they cannot imagine how incredibly fast WhatsApp is, until they try to make something similar. I couldn't understand yet how do they do it, mate. It was just a learning project so I dropped after a while but surely its speed is nowhere comparable to WhatsApp loading time, I am sure there is a smart way that I don't know. If you do research on the topic and get answer, please share, it will be beneficial for many.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which "smart" things Whatsapp uses, but creating a splash activity (welcome screen) which is displayed at app's launch is a good approach. Basically, you start an activity which does nothing except showing the initial screen (logo, animation...) and when all data are loaded, you start an activity with a user interface.

One of many tutorials: [How to create a splash screen](https://android.jlelse.eu/right-way-to-create-splash-screen-on-android-e7f1709ba154)